# SQLite: How to check if database is "ready to be edited"?

Tags: sqlite, javafx

I need your help with a small problem I can't solve. I created a **JavaFX application** that connects with a **local sqlite database** and is able to edit it. All is fine, it works 100%, but when I open the application **twice**, the second application can´t edit the database logically. Is there a save way to check if the database is ready to be edited? 
Hope you can help me!
~ Henri

Comment: By twice you mean two applications at a time? It's not possible to have 2 SQLite connections open at the same time

Comment: @Mibac I know. How can I archieve, that my application recognizes this :D

Comment: Presumably an exception is thrown? You could catch it, thus knowing if the connection failed.

Comment: Yeah, thats how I did it now. Thank you, I thought, there would be a specific method or sth. like that :D

Comment: Is there a reason you need to maintain and open connection (and a lock) on the SQLite DB? Most applications will simply submit their update to the database and then back out to allow more connections.

Comment: It´s an editor of a specific DB made userfriendly. I think yes.